# Configure DataGrip to run whole script by default when executing

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, datagrip

I'm using the 2020.1 version of DataGrip on a Mac and have connected to BigQuery using the recommended Simba JDBC drivers.

If I try run, either with cmd+Enter or pressing the green play button, code with a CTE I get an error that the CTE can't be found, as below. The issue is that only the last line of code is being executed by default. If I select all the text and then execute it runs fine.

[image]

Looking in preferences I see there's options for what gets by default in certain situations. However, even with these set to "Whole script" (and applying and trying restarting) I still get the same issue and still have to select all text to get it to run properly.
[image]

Having to press cmd+a before a executing isn't a deal breaker, it's just annoying. Anyone know how to get the whole script to execute by default on a Mac?

Comment: It doesn't work for unsupported dialects. I created an issue in DataGrip's tracker. Please upvote and comment. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10739

Answer (score 0):

You need change settings in the following way:

- *When inside statement execute* to `Smallest statement`
- *otherwise execute* to `Nothing`
- *for selection execute* to `Exactly as statements`

[image: execution settings]
[image: output]

Comment: To select statement I used `Ctrl+A` and then pressed `Ctrl+Enter`. Are you trying the same?

Comment: I'm aware I can do that, but it's a bit annoying to have to `Ctrl+A` first every time. The question was on how to run the whole script by default, by which I meant with just `Ctrl+Enter`. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: So, let's wait for [DBE-10739](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10739) to be fixed.